# Why Edit text input fill all the other edit texts when navigate to other screen and then come back?

Tags: java, android, navigation, android-edittext, android-navigation

I have a login screen with two edit texts username and password. Once I fill those edit texts and I navigate to register screen using:  `navController.navigate(R.id.registerFragment);` and when I come back to login screen using: `navController.popBackStack();` the password's edit text input is getting copied and replacing the username's edit text. Can someone explain why is this happening?

The steps are simple: fill edit texts -> navigate to register screen -> back to login screen -> the password edit text input has been pasted to the username edit text input.

This image shows the first time I edit the edit texts:
[image]

This image shows the same edit texts, but after I came back from the register screen, where I have been navigated using the register now red text.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example, when you first open the login screen, it is added to the backstack. You enter text into the EditText field and then navigate to the register screen, which is also added to the backstack, overlaying the login screen. When you navigate to the register screen, the login screen remains in the backstack, indicating that it was not cleared or closed. So, when you try to call popBackStack(), it will close the current register screen and show the login screen that was still in the backstack.
Fragment Backstack works in LIFO(Last in First Out) method. So if you want that text in EditText should be cleared, then you have to doit manunally, in onResume method or something like that.

Comment: What do you mean do it manually? Do you mean save the text inside the edit text using shared preferences onPause() and then get the data inside the onResume() method?

Comment: Actually do you want to show the data or not to show the data when nagivating back to the login screen.  To show leave it as it, to not to show, clear textfield data on onPause() or onResume()

Comment: I think you didn't understand the issue. When I type something on password everything i write there when i navigate to register fragment and then go back to login the username text is getting replaced with the password's text. Also this issue occurs when i type password and then change to light/dark mode.

Comment: Ok now I got it, password edittext text reflected to username field?

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. It replaces the username's text with the password's text.